# Regex to match a single character

Tags: java, regex

I was wondering if there was a regex availabe that can match a string and search for a "=" in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but why? I simple string search for "=" is usually what you want (see [String.IndexOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29)). Doing a **search** for "=" using a regex means just using "=" as the regex, nothing special.

If you want to **match** rather than **search** you can use the regex `.*=.*`

Is this what you wanted or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted, I must have though match and search were the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

/[=]+/

That will match if there is an = character one or more times anywhere in the string.

Comment: Why the downvote? That regex will match a string with an = character in it which seems to answer the question. Sure, it's written in Perl syntax, but regexes is regexes.

Comment: Thanks for the backup Cameron :)  Although in hindsight I guess I should have put it in Java friendly syntax.